# Build Responsive page for flutter web and mobile

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout

I want to build the same page for flutter web and mobile part,For responsiveness design I'm using sizer package https://pub.dev/packages/sizer. But the design is too big for web part and looks perfect for mobile part.

Please guide me how to build same page design for mobile and web.

Please refer the below GitHub link for more details
https://github.com/TechnoUrmish/Sizer/issues/38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create two layouts one for web and one for mobile and by the size of the screen your app is running on decide witch layout your showing
this is a sample of the code you need for this action :

```
Scaffold(body: new LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          if(constraints.maxWidth > 1080 || constraints.maxHeight > 1920) {
            return "DesktopLayout"
          } else {
              return "MobileLayout"
          }
        }
    ),  )
```

Comment: @saaeed bayat I have created a flutter layout design for web, the webpage design looks good on browser and same web page looks bad in mobile browser.My current workaround is if(platform.isWeb) means return web layout else mobile layout.

Comment: Please provide perfect solution for this

Comment: 1080 and 1920  values shows different between layouts?

Comment: could you please share working code for this

Comment: you should put your desktop layout in "DesktopLayout" and your mobile layout in "MobileLayout" , but you cant copy your current code in both you have to create a different mobile version and put it on "MobileLayout"

Comment: now you just have web

Comment: the webpage design looks good on browser and same web page looks too small  in mobile browser

Comment: yes because your using the same layout for both, you should create a complatly new layout for mobile

Comment: its like showing two different pages in one

Comment: So if the resolution is mobile resolution then I should return mobile layout design am I right?

Comment: yes that's right